# How to use QGIS Accuracy Assessment plugin?

Tags: qgis, accuracy

I am new user and i want perform accuracy assessment in qgis. I have 1 classified map and another for validation. I have installed the plugin. what am i doing after?

Plugin: http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/accassess/

Docu: https://bitbucket.org/jkibele/accassess/overview

Comment: Could you provide some more detail?

Comment: i have a map of an area of 1500 points classified with random forest. i also have 700 points for validation. i want to perform accuracy assessment in qgis. i have installed the plugin. do i have just to open it and give the refernce and comparison maps??? when i do that i take a archive but is not right.

Comment: Did you use this guide from the plugin? https://bitbucket.org/jkibele/accassess/overview Quote: "To use it, open your raster layers in 
QGis, launch the plugin, select the layer you want to use as the 
reference layer, select your comparison layer, and select an output 
file with a .csv extension. Click 'OK' then open your .csv file with a 
spreadsheet."

Comment: thnks!!!! that is really useful!!